# error:pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"unresolved operator 'Project ['coalesce(scalar-subquery#2375 [], 0)

Tags: apache-spark-sql, subquery

I am running a query using spark sql in pyspark 2.0 the code  is given below

```
spark.sql(
   """select coalesce(
      (select f2.ChargeAmt from Fact_CMCharges where f2.BldgID=f.BldgID limit 1),
     0) as chargval 
     from Fact_CMCharges f 
     join CMRECC l on l.BLDGID=f.BldgID""")
.show()
```

and after running it spark is giving me this exception

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"unresolved operator 'Project ['coalesce(scalar-subquery#2375 [], 0) AS chargval#2376];"
```

how could i solve this
Thanks  in advance
kalyan

Comment: any solution you find for this , even i have similar kind of issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72963925/org-apache-spark-sql-analysisexception-unresolved-operator-project